# How to convert part of nested arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, nest

I would like to know how I can convert date format of each first element included in nested arrays from yyyy-MM-dd into dd/MM/yyyy.
Next is my trial attempt to achieve that but wasn't effective for the purpose.

```
csv_string = CSV.generate(:force_quotes => true) do |csv|
  csv << ['rec_upd_date', 'pro_long_label', 'pro_short_label', 'act_label', 'stt_content', 'stt_label', 'contract_name', 'contract_no', 'accept_no']

  res.each do |row|
    csv << [
      row['REC_UPD_DATE'],
      row['PRO_LONG_LABEL'],
      row['PRO_SHORT_LABEL'],
      row['ACT_LABEL'],
      row['STT_CONTENT'],
      row['STT_LABEL'],
      row['CONTRACT_NAME'],
      row['CONTRACT_NO'],
      row['ACCEPT_NO'] 
    ]
  end
end

File.open('support_incident_statistics.csv', 'w:cp932') do |file|
# w:cp932
  file.write(csv_string)
end

csv = CSV.parse(csv_string)

index = 0;

csv = csv.map{|csvrow|
  if index == 0 then 
    next
  end

  "#{csvrow[0].slice(8,2)}/#{csvrow[0].slice(5,2)}/#{csvrow[0].slice(0,4)}#{csvrow[1]}#{csvrow[2]}#{csvrow[3]}#{csvrow[4]}#{csvrow[5]}#{csvrow[6]}#{csvrow[7]}}"

  index = index +1
}
```

Comment: What way was it not effective?

Comment: csv = csv.map{|csvrow|
  if csvrow[0] == 'rec_upd_date' then 
    next
  end
  #[csvrow[0].to_s.slice(8,2) + "/" + csvrow[0].to_s.slice(5,2) + "/" + csvrow[0].to_s.slice(0,4), csvrow[1], csvrow[2], csvrow[3], csvrow[4], csvrow[5], csvrow[6], csvrow[7], csvrow[8]]
  csvrow.replace([csvrow[0].to_s.slice(8,2) + "/" + csvrow[0].to_s.slice(5,2) + "/" + csvrow[0].to_s.slice(0,4),csvrow[1],csvrow[2],csvrow[3],csvrow[4],csvrow[5],csvrow[6],csvrow[7]])
  
  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how I can convert date format of each first
>   element included in nested arrays from yyyy-MM-dd into dd/MM/yyyy.

Converting yyyy-MM-dd into dd/MM/yyyy format:

```
d = "2015-03-25"
d.to_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# => "25/03/2015"
```

In the provided code its not clear which variable contains date. Assuming its `row['REC_UPD_DATE']`, you can convert it in desired format as:

```
row['REC_UPD_DATE'].to_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```